# How to fill the color of the svg vector icon using css

Tags: html, css, svg, sass

In my application I have the custom vector svg icons like

```
  <i class="stl icon icon-smiley-face" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

By default it is showing in white color but my requirement is to fill the color to yellow.
I tried with

```
stl {
color: yellow;
}
```

but only border colors are changing not filling the icon to yellow color.

Can anyone help me on this

Comment: Could you put a working snippet we can run into your question - so that would include loading the icons. The code you have given has a missing dot before the stl - I assume that isn't the problem in your real code?

Comment: No I put the dot I forgot to add the dot there .Can you advise how to fill the color?then It would be helpful for me

Comment: if so then where did that stl came from,like in font awesome we use `fas` what does stl mean,your example lost some code like import library please make minimal but make it work

Comment: Can you advise - yes but only if you can put your code into your question so we can run it to see the problem for ourselves.

Comment: as u said in other comment [glyph is deprecated use path instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/glyph)

Comment: Don't keep repeatedly asking the same question. Go back to your first question and address the comments posted there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a repeat of a question OP posted yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the information

for SVG style use fill property

```
glyph {
 fill: red;
}
```